No profile link from the main page if the profile was created after migration
We have a question migrated to our stack from another one.
At the time of migration, the original poster didn't have a profile on our site, but later, they created a profile (linked to the original one).
Now, the link to their profile shows up on the migrated question if you go to the question itself, but not from the "top questions" page.


I would expect the link to the profile to be there on the "top questions" page as well.
Can you please fix it?

The profile shown on the home page is in a separate field that doesn't sync with the actual author of the post, even if it is later changed (e.g., due to an author of a migrated post joining the site). Another case of this is when this answer was posted: it was originally posted by a then-staff member who then immediately changed the authorship to Community, but the home page still showed the staff member as the author.
